# Running ApexClasses in PE with Security Review and Certification

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

I have a managed package which I would like to be installed in a Professional Edition.

When I try to install the package in the PE, I get following error, of course, my package has few Apexclasses/Pages/ControllerExtensions etc and does HttpCallouts to a third party WS.

> Installing this package requires the following feature and its
>   associated permissions: Apex Classes

I came across a post somewhere stating that this error would go away if I get my package "Security reviewed and Certified", which seems to be a lengthy process BTW, but not too sure about this.

My question is, does "Security review and Certification" allow me to install the same package in the PE?
Or are PEs missing ApexClasses altogether, i.e my package can only be installed in Enterprise/Unlimited editions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this page from Salesforces documentation. It should answer all your questions. http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/packagingGuide/Content/dev_packages_apex_ge_pe.htm